# Ajax Help Involving Webgrids

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-3.5, webgrid

I'm unexperienced with Ajax. I'm using a webgrid that executes:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Select$1')
```

when a row is selected. How can I call some action when this is posted?

____*UPDATE****_*__*_*___**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.DataItemIndex == -1)
        return;

    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver",
          "this.style.cursor='hand';");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick",
          GetPostBackClientEvent(GridView1,
          "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString())
          );
}
```

Comment: Probably need to see more of your code? and definitely more info?

Comment: definitely. post the __doPostBack() function.

Comment: @AntarrByrd the RowDataBound code you posted is precisely what generates this line: `javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Select$1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote is not Ajax (unless the grid is enclosed in an update panel or something like that).

The way you trigger an event on the server side would be like this:

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "GridView1")
{
    //fire event
    string argument = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUEMENT"];
    //do something.
}
```

**UPDATE**
The important thing is going to be the "argument" piece in my code since it will have the row that the person clicked on in the form of `Select$<RowNumber>`

I guess you need to do something with that information.

Comment: where would I place this? In some predefined event?